# Grails renamed controller is not logging

Tags: grails, logging, controller, rename

I renamed one of my controllers using DOS commands and it stopped logging. All the others controllers created with grails create-controller are still logging.
Are there any files where grails is keeping a reference to controllers names?

I've set 
debug  'grails.app' in config.groovy

I'm using grails 2.2.1, jdk7

Comment: Controller filename and class name should be exactly identical and have Controller at the end of their names. To answer your question, grails does not maintain any other information about the controllers. You can rename it but make sure you follow the convention.

Comment: This is exactly what i did: I renamed the controller file from CommonController.groovy to AppcommonController.groovy

Comment: do grails clean and restart your app,

Comment: Have the clean solved this? Consider answering the question to this left the unanswered list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.The grails clean solved the problem